# 'Any' is not convertible to 'UIView'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Creating a function to randomise images in a grid. Following is a part of the swift code that has been causing problems. Any help is appreciated.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var allImgViews = [Any]()
    var allCenters = [Any]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    //code
    random()
    }

    func random() {
    var centesCopy: [Any] = allCenters
    var randLocInt: Int
    var randLoc: CGPoint
    for any: UIView in allImgViews {
        randLocInt = arc4random() % centersCopy.count
        randLoc = allCenters[randLocInt].cgPoint()
        any.center = randLoc
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: Why are you using `[Any]`?  If the array contains `UIView`s then declare it as `[UIView]`

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you prefer '*Any*' in your code?

Because as far as I can see in your code *allImgViews* seems to be an array of *UIImageView* and *allCenters* be array of *CGPoints*.

Try to use specific data types where ever possible. Use *Any* only if you are planning to use objects of different kind of sub classes of *Any*.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for is

```
for view in allImgViews as! [UIView] {
        // add your logic here
        // 'view' here is a UIView object
    }
```

Suggestion: If you already know that the array will contain UIView objects only, its better to declare it like below

```
var allImgViews = [UIView]()

for view in allImgViews {
    // here the compiler already knows 'view' is a UIView object
    // no need for type casting. 
    //add your logic. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to declare *allCenter* as *CGPoint* and  *allImgViews* as *UIImageView* , you can try this . .

```
func random() {

        var centesCopy: [Any] = allCenters
        var randLocInt: Int
        var randLoc: CGPoint
        for index in stride(from: 0, to: allImgViews.count, by: 1)  {
            randLocInt = Int (arc4random()) % centesCopy.count
            randLoc = self.allCenters[randLocInt] as! CGPoint
            var any = UIView()
            any.center = randLoc
            allImgViews[index] = any
        }
```